# Bootstrap col-md-* orderering when mobile view

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following bootstrap. When display on mobile i am getting

aaa

bbb

ccc

Is it possible to change the order by mobile view to

bbb

aaa

ccc

```
<div class="container innerrow">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                aaa
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                bbb
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                ccc
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the bootstrap helper classes with no need for flex-box ( provided you can edit the HTML).

```
<div class="container innerrow">
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-4">
            bbb
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-pull-4">
            aaa
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            ccc
        </div>
</div>
```

codepen: https://codepen.io/giannidk/full/VWPzMO

Comment: I like this one, very short :)

Answer (score 0):

**CSS Flexbox** allows element reordering:

*HTML*

```
<div class="container innerrow">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 flex">
            <div class="a col-md-4">
                aaa
            </div>
            <div class="b col-md-4">
                bbb
            </div>
            <div class="c col-md-4">
                ccc
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

*CSS*

```
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .a { order: 2 }
  .b { order: 1 }
  .c { order: 3 }
}
```

See [example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eRgWVa).

[a good guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 0):

You could get this result without using flex boxes (which are only supported in IE 11+), albeit with some repetition of your code, as follows.

```
<div class="container innerrow">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="a1 col-md-4 col-hidden-xs">
                aaa
            </div>
            <div class="b col-md-4">
                bbb
            </div>
            <div class="a2 col-md-4 col-visible-xs">
                aaa
            </div>
            <div class="c col-md-4">
                ccc
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So for xs-screens the first div will be hidden and the third one becomes visible.